# Automatically break debugger on Debug.Assert fail

Tags: .net, visual-studio, system.diagnostics

This may seem like a silly question, but no amount of Googling will give me the answer.  In C#, when using the `Debug.Assert` class, a failure causes a MessageBox to show.  Pressing "Retry" goes to the call site in the debugger.  Is there any way to do so automatically i.e. go straight to the call site (skip pressing "Retry" every time?)

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` to suspend execution of the process just as if a debugger breakpoint had been hit:

```
void DebugAssert(bool condition)
{
  if(!condition)
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

Comment: How do I do that automatically on Debug.Assert failing?

Comment: @JeremyMorren Why not replace Debug.Assert with Debugger.Break?

Comment: Because I do not want it to break every time, only when the Assert fails.

Comment: @JeremyMorren To check when the Assert fails use the DebugAssert method in my updated answer.